# How to delete 3d Array' s rows with null value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a 3d Array in JS-DataSeries,like showed below

```
DataSeries[0]=Sun Jun 1 00:00:00 EDT 2014,1664.73,Tue Jul 1 00:00:00 EDT 2014,1683.06,Fri Aug 1 00:00:00 EDT 2014,1708.76

DataSeries[1]=Fri Jun 1 00:00:00 EDT 2012,,Sun Jul 1 00:00:00 EDT 2012,,Wed Aug 1 00:00:00 EDT 2012,,
```

What I wanna do is `if DataSeries[i][j][1]==null`, remove the whole line `DataSeries[i]`. 
Here is my code

```
function checkNullLines(DataSeries) {
    console.log("before" + DataSeries);
    for ( var i = 0; i < DataSeries.length; i++) {
        for ( var j = 0; j < DataSeries[i].length; j++) {

            if (DataSeries[i][j][1] == null) {

                DataSeries[i][j].splice(0, 2);

            }

        }

    }
    console.log("after" + DataSeries +" "+ DataSeries.length);
```

But the execution result is:

```
after,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 1
```

Could you please help me figure out where the error is? Thanks!

Comment: I've corrected my previous answer because you want to remove the whole line `i` from `DataSeries` you need to splice on that collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over an array and modifying it. This requires more attention. Here is an example on how you can achieve this:

```
var i, j, toDelete;

i = 0;
while(i < DataSeries.length)
{
  toDelete = false;
  for (j = 0; j < DataSeries[i].length; j++)
  {
    if(DataSeries[i][j][1] === null)
    {
      toDelete = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if(toDelete)
  {
    DataSeries.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}
```